# Using Meteor's dynamic templates for a splash screen

Tags: javascript, cordova, templates, meteor

I'm in the process of making a Meteor + Cordova app, and was thinking of utilizing Meteor's [Dynamic Templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic) to create a simple splash screen. I would set a Session variable on `Meteor.Startup()`, and then display a dynamic template for a few seconds.

Can this approach, described below, be considered a good one?

The HTML might look like this:

```html
<template name='mainPageWrapper'>

   ...

   {{> Template.dynamic template=getActiveTemplate}}

   ...

</template>
```

And Javascript:

```js
Template.mainPageWrapper.helpers({
  getActiveTemplate: function() {
    return Session.get('activeTemplate');
  }
});
```

How I actually intend the splash screen to work:

I enter the `activeTemplate` Session variable during `Template.mainPageWrapper.onCreated` and change it (to get reactiveness and hide the splash screen after a few seconds' wait in `Template.mainPageWrapper.onRendered`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that what you would end up with would actually be a splash screen. The splash screen in mobile apps is loaded while the app is loading.

What I believe you'd end up with is essentially a loading screen after the app has loaded.